# How to Install PIP3 (for python 3) on Mac without Sudo/Root access?

Tags: python, pip

I am using company Macbook and do not have root nor sudo access but need to have Pip installed for Python 3.
How to achieve this and set PATHs properly after installation (on Mac, not Linux).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install `pip3` without root previlege as follow:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

`pip3` will be installed locally under `/home/$USER/.local/bin/`.

Check the installed version:

```
$HOME/.local/bin/pip3 -V
```

or

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
pip3 --version
```

sample output:

```
pip 10.0.1 from /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: It does NOT create `.local` folder. Are you on Linux or Mac? (question is for mac)

Answer (score -3):

I found this

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >>setup.py
python3 setup.py
```

[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778052/installing-pip3-for-python3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-using-a-proxy).
I have not tested it.

Comment: If you have not tested it / don't know that it works, why post it as an answer?

Comment: Good point, will keep in mind for future comments/answers.